# Powershell: getting Strings out of a tex file and cutting them

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to automate the archiving on some .tex documents in Powershell. I want to filter out the values of some declared variables, like the name.
This is what I have so far after I spent some time on Google.

```
$FamilyNameLine = Select-String $DocFullFileName -Pattern "\\FamilyName{.*?}" | Select Matches
$FamilyName = $FamilyNameLine -replace '\\FamilyName{', ''
```

I tried using this to get the family-name, but it returns

```
@{Matches=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]}
```

after that I would try to cut off the last bracket

While I am still new to Powershell as well as RegEx (I only used it a bit with grep), it feels like i am missing something obvious.

sample input:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{rotating}
\FamilyName{Mustermann}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
```

sample output

```
echo $FamilyName
Mustermann
```

Comment: @melpomene - edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I've understood your primary problem is this line:

```
$FamilyNameLine = Select-String $DocFullFileName -Pattern "\\Surname{.*?}" | Select Matches
```

To retrieve the machting line change your code to:

```
$FamilyNameLine = Select-String $DocFullFileName -Pattern "\\Surname{.*?}" | select  -ExpandProperty Line
```

This returns the lines of the documents where your pattern matches. I've used the `Line` property of the `MatchInfo` object. To retrieve information about properties methods of a method you can use `Get-Member`. Example:

```
Select-String $DocFullFileName -Pattern "\\Surname{.*?}"  | Get-Member
TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo

Name         MemberType Definition                                                       
----         ---------- ----------                                                       
Equals       Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)                                   
GetHashCode  Method     int GetHashCode()                                                
GetType      Method     type GetType()                                                   
RelativePath Method     string RelativePath(string directory)                            
ToString     Method     string ToString(), string ToString(string directory)             
Context      Property   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfoContext      Context {get;set;}
Filename     Property   string Filename {get;}                                           
IgnoreCase   Property   bool IgnoreCase {get;set;}                                       
Line         Property   string Line {get;set;}                                           
LineNumber   Property   int LineNumber {get;set;}                                        
Matches      Property   System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[] Matches {get;set;}        
Path         Property   string Path {get;set;}                                           
Pattern      Property   string Pattern {get;set;}
```

Afterwards you can replace via:

```
$FamilyNames = @() # Empty array
$FamilyNameLine | Foreach-Object { $FamilyNames += ( $_ -replace '\\FamilyName{', '') }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`Select-String` returns an object including, but not limited to, a matches-property which has a collection of match-objects. `Select-Object` will not extract it's value, but create an object with only that property. You're trying to convert that object as a string, which is why it outputs the object's string-definition:

```
@{Matches=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]}
```

which means: one object, with a matches property of type `System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match[]}`

Try using `-ExpandProperty` with `Select-String` to get the match-object directly.

```
$FamilyNameLine = Select-String -InputObject $s -Pattern "\\FamilyName{.*?}" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Matches
$FamilyName = $FamilyNameLine -replace '^\\FamilyName{|}$'

$FamilyName
```

Or you could combine the lines to extract it directly:

```
$FamilyName = Select-String -InputObject $s -Pattern "\\FamilyName{.*?}" | Foreach-Object { $_.Matches.Value -replace '^\\FamilyName{|}$' }

$FamilyName
```

I modified your replace to remove the trailing `}` too.